Internal energy and enthalpy
Consider 2 cases for the same amount of gas,
State I: ( P_1 ) and ( V_1 )
State II: ( P_2 ) and ( V_2 )
Now, the internal energy change ( Delta U ) when going from state 1 to state 2 is equal to the sum of heat absorbed or released ( Q ) and the work done ( W ) to change the volume from ( V_1 ) to ( V_2 ). (Note: Since the pressure is variable, this term changes.)
[ Delta U = Q - W ]
Anyways, how do we define the change in enthalpy ( Delta H ) here? Is it the sum of the change in internal energy and the work done?
[ Delta H = Delta U + Delta (PV) ]
What work done? Is it the same work done ( W )?
just need to know whether the 2 work done terms PV and w are same or different, if different in what way ?

what i think
I thought that both terms were same, but since i knew that in cases where pressure is not constant enthalpy is not equal to heat, so i knew i was wrong, but didn't know the distinction between these terms
then i had this idea "PV term is just the work required to maintain the shape, here the work required to maintain V2 against atmospheric pressure, and the w term included the work we did or gas did to reach the second state"
The term
w
in deltaU = q + w captures all forms of work done during a process including variations due to changing pressures.
The term
PV
in deltaH = deltaU + PV specifically accounts for energy associated with maintaining pressure against volume changes at any given state.
I truly understood their distinction when i considered a non-isobaric process, i considered the same 2 states, now for internal energy change the work done term is an integral as it depends on the path, wheras the (P2V2-P1V1)term is actually the excess energy consumed to make V2 comapred to the energy required to make V1 ... when pressure is constant these terms cancel out, as both would be P(deltaV)

Note the the work sign convention in chemistry considers as positive work done on the system (ΔU = Q + W), in opposite to convention "work done by the system" in engineering and until recently in physics too ( ΔU = Q - W). // Note that Δ(pV) = -W is valid only for special cases when p=const, or if integral(p .dV) from from one state to another is by chance equal to Δ(pV).

Is it supposed to be an ideal gas?

First: you are comparing States not cases. Second: U and H are STATE FUNCTIONS, independent of path; Q and W are path functions; they will change with mechanism. Break the path into steps that can be measured thermally and physically ,combine Q and W etc to get the state functions. First reread your PChem text[s] several times to get a better idea of what is going on.

You don’t need to know Q or W to solve this problem for an ideal gas.

now i know the distinction between these terms

yea gas is ideal

You can find tons of useful educative info if you google respective keywords together with "site:libretexts.org" which is a site of joint effort of multiple universities to provide various lectures online.

For an idea gas, $\Delta U=nC_v(T_2-T_1)$ and $\Delta H=nC_p(T_2-T_1)$.  What do you get if you combine these equations with the ideal gas law?

so basically the work term in internal energy change is a path function, wheras the PV term in enthalpy is just P(V-0) [work to occupy that shape], this term seems like a state function, is this it ? (thanks for the resource Poutnik :))

@ChetMiller, i think we will end up with PV, as Cp-Cv = R, we get (nRdeltaT), [deltaH-deltaU = PV], since it is dellta T and not simply T, i guess we subract volumes, this seems like a pressure constant environment ...

Good luck with that
